# Unable to save data from both forms

Tags: python, django, django-models, saving-data

I am trying to get Seller information, username, password, name, mobile number and address. I have used User to get the username and password, connected the username to my model through OneToOneField relationship and later save the information.

I have made a model named SellerDetails which gets the user field from OneToOneField with User and rest all details are provided as follows:

```
#models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class SellerDetails(models.Model):
    """docstring for SellerDetails."""
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null = True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    mobile_number = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

then I have made two forms in my forms.py

```
#forms.py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from avkara.models import SellerDetails, VendorDetails

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordInput())
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password')

class SellerDetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """docstring for SellerDetailsForm."""
    class Meta:
        model = SellerDetails
        fields = ('name','address','mobile_number')


#Then I tried established a relation while saving the form

#views.py
def Signup_seller(request):
    seller_registered = False

    if request.method == "POST":
        user_form = UserForm(data = request.POST)
        user_details = SellerDetailsForm(data = request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid() and user_details.is_valid():
            seller = user_form.save()
            seller.set_password(seller.password)

            seller.save()

            #saving user_details now
            other_details = user_details.save(commit= False)
            other_details.user = seller
            other_details.save()

            seller_registered = True

    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        user_details = SellerDetailsForm()

    return render(request, 'avkara/signup_seller.html',{'seller_registered': seller_registered , 'user_form' : user_form, 'user_details' : user_details})


#Then I tried serving both forms through Html form. Here is my html
#signup_seller.html
<div class="container jumbotron">
      <h2>Sign up</h2><br><br><br>
      <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{ user_form.as_p }}
          {{ user_details.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
    </div>

#The desired out should be Thank you for registering but I get following error 
IntegrityError at /avkara/signup_seller
NOT NULL constraint failed: avkara_sellerdetails.password

#This is error it is showing

F:\Webpage\python\techforstock\avkara\views.py in Signup_seller
other_details.save() <!--error part --!>
```

I have worked one it for hours, but no luck, Can Anyone help me out with this.

I want the username and password to be registered in users section and other information saved in Sellerdetails when I open Admin interface, but it should be with respect to the specific username.

Comment: The error is telling you there is a problem with the `password` field in sellerdetails. But the model you have shown doesn't have a password field there. Are you sure that is the correct model code?

Comment: Yes it the correct code!

Comment: But do you have a password column in the database table for some reason?

Comment: Yes I have password field. It is in userForm in Forms.py

Comment: No. The error shows that you have a password column in the `sellerdetails` table in the database.

Comment: I guess that is because I have defined a OneToOneField for user

Comment: No. That is not the reason.

Comment: I have not done that, how can I now fix that?

Comment: I guess your database is out of sync somehow. If you don't have any data you need to keep, you could drop it and run migrations again.

Comment: It worked! I deleted the database and then ran the migrate, it works

Comment: turns out that the modification I made in python code was not reflected in the db.sqlite3 file